# How can we parse rpc formatted xml request in Spring Rest controllers?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, xml-rpc, spring-restcontroller

I have Spring Based Rest Controller Below is the sample request and content type sent to controller.

Content-Type: text/xml
Sample rpc xml sent in request is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>search</methodName>
   <params>
  <param>
     <value>
        <struct>
           <member>
              <name>name</name>
              <value>
                 <array>
                    <data>
                       <value>
                          <string>do</string>
                       </value>
                    </data>
                 </array>
              </value>
           </member>
           <member>
              <name>summary</name>
              <value>
                 <array>
                    <data>
                       <value>
                          <string>do</string>
                       </value>
                    </data>
                 </array>
              </value>
           </member>
        </struct>
     </value>
  </param>
  <param>
     <value>
        <string>or</string>
     </value>
  </param>
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow the bellow code may it useful to you.

Here In spring-rest controller by default, it will parse into JSON.
we need to add XML parsing in method level like following code.

**Note**: add consume type like JSON,XML..etc, here telling to controller in which format we need to parse.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = { RequestMethod.GET },consumes = { 
      MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public String test() {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: rpc xml are different from normal xml . Can you share working code snippet.